# Product of differences in a k-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I've been studying abstract algebra from a book "Elementary Abstract Algebra" by W. Edwin Clark, and I've come across a problem I don't know how to approach:

> **Problem 3.17 (Challenge Problem)** For $\sigma \in S_n$ prove that:
>
> $\sigma$ is even $\Leftrightarrow \prod_{i<k} \frac{\sigma(k)-\sigma(i)}{k - i} = 1$
>
> $\sigma$ is odd $\Leftrightarrow \prod_{i<k} \frac{\sigma(k)-\sigma(i)}{k - i} = -1$

$S_n$ is defined as a set of all permutations on the set $[n]=\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$

EDIT:

As @orlp explained in the comments, the equivalent of this problem is:
$$\prod_{k=2}^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{\sigma(k)-\sigma(i)}{k-i}=sign(\sigma)$$

I've tried using induction on $n$ - proving that the conjecture is true for each $\sigma \in S_2$ was easy, but I don't know how to apply the $S_n$ case in order to prove for $S_{n+1}$. Maybe induction isn't the best way to do it.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I think you're misreading $\prod_{i<k}$, it's shorthand for $\prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}$ (assuming zero based indexing), if using 1-based indexing it's $\prod_{k=2}^n\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}$.

Comment: @orlp I believe I'm not, but here's the screenshot of the page just for reference:
https://imgur.com/a/QiQuY

Comment: No, I believe you are misreading it, and that in this case the correct interpretation is $$\prod_{k=2}^n\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{\sigma(k) - \sigma(i)}{k-i} = \text{sign}(\sigma).$$

Comment: @orlp Oh, it makes sense now. Is it common practice to write $\prod_{i<k}$ as $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}$?

Comment: It is somewhat common yes. I read $\prod_{i<k}f(i, k)$ as "the product of all $f(i, k)$ such that $1 \leq i < k \leq n$".

Comment: It may be helpful to recognize that the set of transpositions is: $\{(i\ k) \in S_n: i,k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\} \text{ and } i < k\}$. Writing transpositions so the smaller integer comes first allows us to ensure we list each transposition exactly once.